# Is there a CSV Writer NuGet that uses SystemInterface.IO instead of System.IO?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csv

I started to use CsvHelper by Josh Close, but it uses System.IO.TextWriter, not SystemInterface.IO.
I want to be able to unit test my code without actually creating files.
Does anyone know of a similar helper app that uses SystemInterface.IO?

Thanks!

Comment: If you wonder where `SystemInterface.IO` comes from, see [SystemWrapper](https://systemwrapper.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Ah! Thanks. I didn't understand where SystemInterface was coming from - but found it useful to be able to unit test the File.IO... Exactly what it was designed for!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the CsvHelper classes implement interfaces, you can actually mock those

```
public class CsvReader : ICsvReader
public class CsvWriter : ICsvWriter
etc.
```

See: https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/tree/master/src/CsvHelper